# Properly defining RefObject with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Hi all I'm new to typescript and I'm trying to define a type for a RefObject of type HTMLAudioElement but I'm getting this error.

```
Type 'MutableRefObject<HTMLAudioElement>' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLAudioElement': addEventListener, removeEventListener, autoplay, buffered, and 320 more.
```

I have my type defined as

```
export interface AudioState {
  audioRef: RefObject<HTMLAudioElement | undefined>;
  playing: boolean;
  progress: number;
  duration: number;
  volume: number;
}
```

I'm trying to use it like this;

```
dispatch({
  name: 'SET_AUDIO',
  audioRef: useRef<HTMLAudioElement | undefined>(new Audio(url)),
});
```

How can I prevent the type error here? TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error message is saying that you are assigning a `RefObject` of an `HTMLAudioElement` (an object with a property `.current` which is an `HTMLAudioElement`) to something that expects to receive the `HTMLAudioElement` itself.  Instead of using `myRef` you should be using `myRef.current`.

I have some major concerns about your code.  **Calling `useRef` inside of a `dispatch` is a violation of the rules of hooks.**  If this is Redux then you don't want to be storing a non-serializable object like an HTML element.

But probably what you want is to use the `HTMLAudioElement` directly and ditch the ref.

```
export interface AudioState {
  audioElement: HTMLAudioElement | undefined;
  playing: boolean;
  progress: number;
  duration: number;
  volume: number;
}

dispatch({
  name: 'SET_AUDIO',
  audioElement: new Audio(url),
});
```